# Heroku PG error on select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I have a piece of code working great in dev environment and firing an error in production. Here it is:

```
venue.badges.where(:active => true).select([:title, :desc, :bonus]).each do |badge|
```

While working on MySQL local DB, it fires this in production:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "desc"
: SELECT title, desc, bonus FROM "badges"  WHERE "badges"."venue_id" = 22 AND "badges"."active" = 't'):
LINE 1: SELECT title, desc, bonus FROM "badges"  WHERE "badges"."ven...
```

I really don't get what's wrong here.

Comment: One thing that is wrong is that you're developing on top of one database and deploying on top of another, that's just a shortcut to pain and suffering. There are a lot of subtle differences between databases and no ORM will protect you from those differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESC is a reserved keyword in SQL. [This list of SQL and PostgreSQL keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) is a good reference. To use a reserved word as a column name you need escape it with double quotes:

```
SELECT title, "desc", bonus FROM badges WHERE ...
```

And in rails, pass it as a literal string rather than a symbol:

```
venue.badges.where(:active => true).select([:title, '"desc"', :bonus]).each do |badge|
```

Comment: Or better, rename the column to something that isn't a reserved word, that'll be less painful in the long run.